# Как подключится к Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, macos, rdp, gnome

У меня есть удаленный сервер. На нем стоит Ubuntu 16. Я поставил там Gnome. Как мне подключится из под Mac Os к этому удаленному рабочему столу?

Comment: Вот [неплохая инструкция](http://web.archive.org/web/20100719220308/http://blog.ibd.com/sysadmin/bonjour-avahi-netatalk-to-share-files-files-between-ubuntu-10-4-mac-os-x/) по установке и настройке демонов. А здесь рассказывается [о SSH-клиентах для OS X](https://habrahabr.ru/post/186380/). Так же можно [использовать VNC](http://digitalsanctum.com/2013/03/13/how-to-setup-vnc-between-a-mac-and-ubuntu/), но народ пишет, что работает не слишком быстро.

Comment: это не то, мне надо подключится к удаленному рабочему столу

Comment: SSH -X или VNC.